# How to automate chrome browser in webdriver? i am getting an error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
 public void chrome(){

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleChrome"); //Chrome
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.close();
driver.quit();
}
```

running this method throw an error "[4032:519:0701/155158:ERROR:process_singleton_mac.cc(106)] Unable to obtain profile lock."

Answer (score 4):

Download the ChromeDriver.exe from [[http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list]](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) then add the system property as,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "...\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Path of chromedriver.exe file should be proper.
hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the path ChromeDriver before creating ChromeDriver instance

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/test/ChromeDriverMac/chromedriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Download chromedriver from below location

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: This is the best answer. +1 for you